# Вопрос по методу filter() в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Из массива чекбоксов нужно получить лишь те, у которых атрибут 'data-set-chld' равен атрибуту 'data-set-parent' того, на который кликнули.

Мой вариант:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
        let thisParent = $(this).attr('data-set-parent')
        let setProducts = $("input[type=checkbox]").filter((item) => {
            return $(this).attr('data-set-chld') == thisParent
        })
        console.log(setProducts)
}
```

С методом filter() ранее не работал, поэтому написал интуитивно, особо не надеясь на корректный результат.

Comment: ну дак и чего с кодом не так-то ?

Comment: С каждым новым кликнутым чекбоксом, нужно делать проверку для всех кликнутых чекбоксов? Или только для последнего?

Comment: @teran Он мне все чекбоксы в консоль показывает, хотя искомых примерно половина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
        let thisParent = $(this).data('set-parent');
        let setProducts = $("input[type=checkbox]").filter((idx, el) => {
            return $(el).data('set-chld') == thisParent;
        });
console.log(setProducts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1" data-set-parent="0" data-set-chld="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="2" data-set-parent="1" data-set-chld="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="3" data-set-parent="1" data-set-chld="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="4" data-set-parent="2" data-set-chld="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="5" data-set-parent="2" data-set-chld="0" />
```